# Plotting only one level of a factor in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, factors

```
vector1 <- c(1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 5, 8)
vector2 <- c("level1", "level2", "level2", "level1", "level3", "level2", "level2", "level3")
dataframe <- data.frame(vector1, vector2)
dataframe$vector2 <- as.factor(dataframe$vector2)


plot <- ggplot(dataframe, aes(vector2, vector1))
plot +geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Say you have a class imbalance in factor 1 and you want to focus on a bar plot that isolates just factor one as a singular bar chart. How can I make it be the only level to show up on the x-axis?

Comment: You could just call `ggplot(dataframe %>% filter(factor = "level1"))`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get "ErrorL filter() takes unnamed arguments. Do you need '=='?

Comment: Yeah that's my typo, use `factor == "level1"`

Comment: and when you want to increase the number of levels without typing each level manually?